# Is it possible to require a Ruby file in an ERB template?

Tags: ruby, erb

I know that you can embed Ruby code in an ERB template. But I have this massive file that has over 200 lines of code. It wouldn't make sense to place every line into the ERB file as then the page would be too big.

I think a better solution would be to require a Ruby file in ERB. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

My code itself has a lot of methods defined and I'm not sure they can be added to a view file anyways.

The program is a game that will be played on the home page.

Comment: how about using partials or putting your code in helpers?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of code will this ruby file have?

Comment: I've never done it because it's not common convention. If using rails, then copy all of that code into a model and connect it with your controller. Otherwise I guess you could try to put <% require 'filename.rb' %> at the top of your erb. Test it out let me know how it goes.

Comment: Do I put the code in ApplicationHelper or ControllerNameHelper?